# Run filter on sorted array results then create new array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

OK so my problem yesterday regarding sorting XML results into an associative array, that works fine. ( see my code here )

```
  <?php 

$xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);
$curdate = date('d/m/Y');

$new_array = array();
$limit = 5;
$c = 0;
foreach ($xml->event as $event) {
    if ($limit == $c) {
        break;
    }
    $c++;
    $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
    $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
    $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
    $eventt = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
    $new_array[$eventy.$eventm.$eventd.$eventt] = array(
        'eventd' => $eventd,
        'eventm' => $eventm,
        'eventy' => $eventy,
        'eventt' => $eventt,
        'eventdate' => $eventd.'/'.$eventm.'/'.$eventy,
        'eventid' => $event->attributes()->{'eventid'},
        'eventtime' => $event->attributes()->{'time'},
        'eventname' => $event->attributes()->{'name'},
        'venue' => $event->attributes()->venue,
    );
}

ksort($new_array);
foreach ($new_array as $event_time => $event_data) {
    echo "<a href=\"event/".$event_data['eventname']."/".$event_data['eventid']."\">".$event_data['venue'].' - '.$event_data['eventtime'].' - '.$event_data['eventname']."</a><br />".$event_data['eventdate']."<br />";
}
?>
```

My problem now is that there are records in the xml feed that have blank values
so I need to now somehow run a filter so that if the date attribute value is empty or less than 2016 it is NOT shown and the results must also be sorted by the $event_data['eventtime'] value

thanks in advance

**FIXED**

```
<?php
$new_array = array();
//$limit = 5;
//$c = 0;
foreach ($xml->event as $event) {
    //if ($limit == $c) {
    //    break;
    //}
    $checkdate = date('Ymd');
        if($event->attributes()->{'date'} == $checkdate) {

    $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
    $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
    $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
    $startdate = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,8);
    $eventt = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
    $new_array[$startdate.$eventt] = array(
        'startdate' => $startdate,
        'eventt' => $eventt,
        'eventd' => $eventd,
        'eventm' => $eventm,
        'eventy' => $eventy,
        'eventdate' => $eventd.'/'.$eventm.'/'.$eventy,
        'eventid' => $event->attributes()->{'eventid'},
        'eventtime' => $event->attributes()->{'time'},
        'eventname' => $event->attributes()->{'name'},
        'venue' => $event->attributes()->venue,
    );
}
}
ksort($new_array);
$showl = 10;
$n = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $event_time => $event_data) {
        if($showl ==$n){ break;}$n++;       
    $replace = array("/"," ");
    $eventname = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['eventname']);
    $venue = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['venue']);
    echo "<a href=\"event/".$venue."/".$eventname."/".$event_data['eventid']."\">".$event_data['venue'].' - '.$event_data['eventtime'].' - '.$event_data['eventname']."</a><br />";
}
}
?>
```

Thats what I was trying to do but could think how lol my mind went blank

Comment: Why not to check if the attribute is empty prior to adding it to the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function GHList5() {
$xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Greyhounds.xml';
//  $xmlData = 'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlData);
$curdate = date('d/m/Y');

$new_array = array();
//$limit = 5;
//$c = 0;
foreach ($xml->event as $event) {
//    if ($limit == $c) {
//        break;
//    }
    $checkdate = date('Ymd');
        if($event->attributes()->{'date'} == $checkdate) {

    $eventd = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},6,2);
    $eventm = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},4,2);
    $eventy = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,4);
    $startdate = substr($event->attributes()->{'date'},0,8);
    $eventt = $event->attributes()->{'time'};
    $new_array[$startdate.$eventt] = array(
        'startdate' => $startdate,
        'eventt' => $eventt,
        'eventd' => $eventd,
        'eventm' => $eventm,
        'eventy' => $eventy,
        'eventdate' => $eventd.'/'.$eventm.'/'.$eventy,
        'eventid' => $event->attributes()->{'eventid'},
        'eventtime' => $event->attributes()->{'time'},
        'eventname' => $event->attributes()->{'name'},
        'venue' => $event->attributes()->venue,
    );
}
}
ksort($new_array);
$showl = 10;
$n = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $event_time => $event_data) {
        if($showl ==$n){ break;}$n++;       
    $replace = array("/"," ");
    $eventname = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['eventname']);
    $venue = str_replace($replace,'-', $event_data['venue']);
    echo "<a href=\"event/".$venue."/".$eventname."/".$event_data['eventid']."\">".$event_data['venue'].' - '.$event_data['eventtime'].' - '.$event_data['eventname']."</a><br />";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use DOM, you can use a PHP function to filter the nodes using Xpath.

#### Filter

```
function isNewerThen($current, $minimum) {
  return $current >= $minimum;
}

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace("p", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions('isNewerThen');

$expression = '/category/event[
  p:function(
    "isNewerThen", 
    concat(@date, "T", @time, "Z"), 
    "20160106T1600Z"
  )
]';

$events = iterator_to_array(
  $xpath->evaluate($expression)
);
```

`concat()` is an Xpath function that glues all arguments together as strings. The arguments can be nodes, node lists, scalars or literals. If it is a node list the first node will be cast to a string.

`p:function` is resolved to `{http://php.net/xpath}:function` and allows you to call a PHP function from Xpath. The first argument is the function name. All other arguments are passed to the call. In you case the attributes can be used as parts of an ISO 8601 date time value.

`iterator_to_array` converts the returned `DOMNodeList` into an array.

#### Sort

The array elements are still DOM nodes. You can use Xpath with them or use the DOM Api methods to get attributes and compare them. `usort` allows you to sort the array using an compare function.

```
usort(
  $events,
  function($nodeA, $nodeB) {
    $timeA = sprintf('%sT%sZ', $nodeA->getAttribute('date'), $nodeA->getAttribute('time'));
    $timeB = sprintf('%sT%sZ', $nodeB->getAttribute('date'), $nodeB->getAttribute('time'));
    return strtotime($timeA) - strtotime($timeB);
  } 
);

foreach ($events as $event) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(@meeting)', $event), " ";
  echo $event->getAttribute('date'), " ";
  echo $event->getAttribute('time'), "\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
Portman Park 20160106 1600
Marseille V' 20160106 1605
Kempton 20160106 1610
Steepledowns 20160106 1620
...
```